# The following code's not running completely

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error, terminate

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner xis = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insira o deslocamento desejado.");
    int d = xis.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Digite a mensagem a ser enviada.");
    String m = xis.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) 
    {

        int x = m.charAt(i) + d;
        if(x > 'Z')
        {
            System.out.println((char)(x - 26));
        }
        System.out.println((char)x); 
    }

}
```

That's what the console shows:

Insira o deslocamento desejado.

14 // user's entry

Digite a mensagem a ser enviada.

//
After that it says it's been terminated.

I dont understand why it won't run the whole code, is it a problema with the code or with my eclipse?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I got it right now, "xis.nextLine", was the thing making it wrong.

Comment: If the input contains whitespaces `xis.next()` will get only the first word.

Comment: Well, yeah, I did not notice this. I tried with one word and it was working, didint think about this. Thanks for noticing. @AndersonVieira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert the number and hit enter, the call to `xis.nextInt()` consumes the integer but doesn't consume the next line character. So when you do `xis.nextLine()`, it reads the next line character and finishes.

A workaround is to add another call to `nextLine()` just after `nextInt()`, like this:

```
System.out.println("Insira o deslocamento desejado.");
int d = xis.nextInt();
xis.nextLine();
System.out.println("Digite a mensagem a ser enviada.");
String m = xis.nextLine();
```

Comment: this is actually the right answer.. thanks @AndersonVieira for the comment dint test with white spaces..

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is small change you have to use next instaed od nextLine.. Below is the necessary code also if you enter number in wrong format you will get a mismatch exception.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner xis = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insira o deslocamento desejado.");
        int d = xis.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite a mensagem a ser enviada.");
        String m = xis.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) 
        {

            int x = m.charAt(i) + d;
            if(x > 'Z')
            {
                System.out.println((char)(x - 26));
            }
            System.out.println((char)x); 
        }
        xis.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is terminated because when you are using Scanner class for input, it will take 'Enter' as a input.

So when you input 14 and press 'enter', so it will take two input. first is 14 and second is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I *think* has happened.

- The `Scanner` as read '1' and '4' and returned you 14 from `xis.nextInt()`
- The very next thing in the input is a new line (the return you entered after the 14 was typed).
- You then read a line of input, which will read and return everything up to the next new line.  In this case this is an empty string, which is what `xis.nextLine()` returns.
- If you then read *another* line I think you may get the rest of your input.

To test this after `String m = xis.nextLine();` just add:

`m = xis.nextLine();`

This is probably not the best way to code this - but it should indicate whether what I have suggested above is actually what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can use BufferedReader class. Show below code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        //Scanner xis = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Insira o deslocamento desejado.");
        //int d = xis.nextInt();
        int d = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Digite a mensagem a ser enviada.");
        //String m = xis.nextLine();
         String m = br.readLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) 
        {

            int x = m.charAt(i) + d;
            if(x > 'Z')
            {
                System.out.println((char)(x - 26));
            }
            System.out.println((char)x); 
        }
    }
}
```